# how do I change debug to release using conan manager, msvc and cmake

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, conan

Using conan manager with build_type=Release, the generator still uses Debug configuration see below. I don't want to use any additional .json file to setup the behavior. Any idea how to do that by using conan manager?

I found out that this:
cmake --build . --config Release -j
command changes debug configuration to release but I don't know how to do that in conan.

[settings]
os=Windows
os_build=Windows
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
compiler=Visual Studio
compiler.version=16
build_type=Release

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe /c /IC:.conan\f23e85\1\include /IC:.conan\733d7c\1\include /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR="Debug"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR /Fo"MyOpenCV.dir\Debug\" /Fd"MyOpenCV.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue C:\Users\Peter\source\repos\MyOpenCV\src\main.cpp
> main.cpp

Solution to my question

missing setup in CMakeLists.txt file from generated conanbuildinfo.cmake file

> include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
> conan_basic_setup()

and at the end

> conan_target_link_libraries(MyOpenCV)

Comment: Could you please clarify what you're trying to achieve and which commands are you executing?

Comment: I found out that I was doing all wrong in my CMakeLists.txt file was missing basic setup from generated files by cmake. "include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake) conan_basic_setup()"
and at the end
"conan_target_link_libraries(MyOpenCV)"